# How to get the text of drop down values in squish tool?

Tags: python, automation, squish

I have to verify the text of drop down list elements. How can I verify the same using python script in squish tool ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Naive approach:**

Record (then replay) selecting each of the entries. Use exception handling to log accessing individual entries and be able to proceed to test script execution.

**More flexible approach:**

Recording selecting one of the entries. This gives you script code to make the open the drop down and the object name of the drop down list. Then use [object.children()](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#object.children-function) to get all child elements of the drop down list object.

Pseudo example:

```
drop_down_list = waitForObject(...)
children = object.children(drop_down_list)
test.verify("Entry 1", children[0].text)
```

(You have to check the properties of the children to see which actual property contains the text or whatever else you want to verify.)